# How do I create a listview with add/remove buttons and edit in place like in the Contacts or People app?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Do I need to subclass MvxAdapter in some way or is this a control that would have to inherit from MvxListView?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Adapter that extend BaseAdapter and use a custom layout

Comment: Are there any examples for this scenario?  I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Check out this link http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-adapter-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply proceed with a custom `ListView`.
Here is a nice tutorial on custom ListViews.

[www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)